# How to achieve MongoDB nested lookup inside array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am doing an aggregation in **Paper** collection like below

```
const papers = await Paper.aggregate([
                        {
                            "$lookup": {
                                "from": "reviews",
                                "localField": "reviewId",
                                "foreignField": "_id",
                                "as": "review"
                            }
                        },
                        { $unwind: '$review' }
                        
                    ]);
```

It returns the result that contains **review** object which has a **reviews** array like:

```
[
  {
    ...
    review: {
      _id: 5f1638770f3a8d20f8c1beeb,
      reviews: [Array],
    },
   ...
  }
]
```

**If I make the review more clear**, it is like below:

```
{
  _id: 5f1638770f3a8d20f8c1beeb
  reviews: [
    {
      _id: 5f164395857bcdd1d8674b69,
      reviewerId: 5f15b28d534b5886c0d9eb8a
    },
    {
      _id: 5f164395857bcdd1d8674b6a,
      reviewerId: 5f1358c523dc2367c43a6311
    }
  ]
}
```

In above, **reviewerId** inside **reviews** array refers to user id from **"users"** collection. I want to get users name, email, and address in reviews array like below:

```
{
      reviews: [
        {
          _id: 5f164395857bcdd1d8674b69,
          reviewerId: 5f15b28d534b5886c0d9eb8a
          reviewer : {
            name:"some_name",
            email:"abc@example.com"
          }
        },
        {
          _id: 5f164395857bcdd1d8674b6a,
          reviewerId: 5f1358c523dc2367c43a6311
          reviewer : {
            name:"some_name",
            email:"efg@example.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You'll have to `$unwind: '$review'` then `$lookup` and `$group` them back together

Comment: @thammada.ts can you please give me an example based on my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the structure of your collection almost similar as I mention below in the Mongo playground.

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$reviews",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      localField: "reviews.reviewerId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "reviews.reviewer"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      question: {
        $first: "$question"
      },
      reviews: {
        $addToSet: "$reviews"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WBCYRfm4yaI)

Comment: In my case, I want the **reviewer** by aggregation in Paper collection, not separately in reviews collection. Can I  use nested lookup here? if yes, please give me an example.

Comment: I think u have edited the question. When u edit the queation, please note something that u have updated, bcs meanwhile few developers working on your queation. Ahh.. Why dont u provide all collection sample format to have a look?

Comment: @verman - I tried not to mention unnecessary things. I thought it would become more verbose :( Would you please suggest me how can I achieve the same result what you answered above from **paper** collection, not separately from **reviews** collection? In My question **reviews** are under **review** object (please look at the question). I want to populate **reviewer** from there. I would be very grateful if you help me to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, we can help. But  we need to know who you designed the collection. So update how the collections seem